# Symfony - generate url with parameter in controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

I want to generate a Url directly in my controller. I want to user a url defined in my routing.yml file that needs a parameter.

I've found that code in the Cookbook (Routage section) :

```
$params = $router->match('/blog/my-blog-post');
// array('slug' => 'my-blog-post', '_controller' => 'AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show')

$uri = $router->generate('blog_show', array('slug' => 'my-blog-post'));
// /blog/my-blog-post
```

But I don't understand to what is refering the $router. Obviously, it doesn't work.
Is there a simple way to generate a routing url with a paramter in a controller ?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

It's pretty simple :

```
public function myAction()
{
    $url = $this->generateUrl('blog_show', array('slug' => 'my-blog-post'));
}
```

Inside an action, $this->generateUrl is an alias that will use the router to get the wanted route, also you could do this that is the same :

```
$this->get('router')->generate('blog_show', array('slug' => 'my-blog-post'));
```

Answer (score 21):

If you want absolute urls, you have the third parameter.

```
$product_url = $this->generateUrl('product_detail', 
    array(
        'slug' => 'slug'
    ),
    UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL
);
```

Remember to include UrlGeneratorInterface.

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
```

Answer (score 13):

Get the router from the container.

```
$router = $this->get('router');
```

Then use the router to generate the Url

```
$uri = $router->generate('blog_show', array('slug' => 'my-blog-post'));
```

Answer (score 3):

make sure your controller extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;`

you should also check `app/console debug:router` in terminal to see what name symfony has named the route

in my case it used a minus instead of an underscore

i.e `blog-show`

```
$uri = $this->generateUrl('blog-show', ['slug' => 'my-blog-post']);
```